# Group of operators such that $|T(t)x|\geq c |x|$

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, banach-spaces, semigroup-of-operators

Let $X$ be a Banach space. Can I have an example of a [strongly continuous group of operators](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C0-semigroup)  $T(t)$  such that 
$$|T(t)x|\geq c |x|, \ t\in\mathbb{R}$$with $c>1$.

For $c=1$, I know examples of groups of isometries. In general we have this estimation
$$|T(t)x|\leq Me^{\omega |t|} |x|, \ t\in\mathbb{R}.$$

Comment: You always have $T(0) = \operatorname{id}$.

Comment: Ah yes, thanks, I didn't see that.